# StandardIn has not been redirected C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on HWID spoofer project, it writes a amidewin to C:\Program Files from resources. But when i want to use it with commands, i get a StandardIn has not been redirected exception. Here is my code.

```
               Random rnd = new Random();
            Process aws = new Process();


            if (mode == 0) 
            {
                aws.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                aws.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                aws.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                aws.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                aws.Start();
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine($"cd {Infos.MainPath}");
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /BS " + rnd.Next(5, 9).ToString());
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /SS " + rnd.Next(5, 9).ToString());
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /SU auto");
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /SK " + rnd.Next(5, 9).ToString());
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /SF " + rnd.Next(5, 9).ToString());
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /CS " + rnd.Next(5, 9).ToString());
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("AMIDEWINx64.exe /PSN " + rnd.Next(5, 9).ToString());
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            }
```

Comment: I doubt that you can use stdin with cmd.exe in that way. I think it would be simpler to create a batch file, and then tell cmd.exe to run that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thx for idea, i'll do with this way.

Comment: @itsReinsy Following seems to work. Perhaps the problem is in one of the commands:

` String path = "C:\\Temp\\Test";
            {
                aws.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                aws.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                aws.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                aws.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                aws.Start();
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd {0}", path);
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("rmdir /S todelete");
                aws.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Process" object is two-part for the input and output redirection.  The property setting to TRUE to ALLOW the redirect is part 1.  You need the set the STREAM of the input in your process object.

```
                // the aws just to show same context as in your code of the PROCESS object
                var aws = new Process();

                // get the INPUT STREAM from that process
                var myStreamWriter = aws.StandardInput;

                // and put in whatever values you want to provide to that stream
                myStreamWriter.WriteLine("FirstStreamToPass");
                myStreamWriter.WriteLine("AnotherStreamValue");
                myStreamWriter.WriteLine("LastValueToSend");

                // close it when you are done
                myStreamWriter.Close();


                // NOW call your process
                aws.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I think here calling `aws.WaitForExit`  without sending `exit` would hang it indefinitely.