# StandardIn has not been redirected

Tags: c#, .net

I'm always getting an error:

> StandardIn has not been redirected

from running this code:

```
namespace test_cmd
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            process.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(RunCommand(process.Id));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string RunCommand(int procId)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(procId);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("whoami" + "\n"); // THIS LINE
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked this topic [StandardIn has not been redirected C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243672/standardin-has-not-been-redirected-c-sharp) but couldn't solve the issue. My main purpose is accessing a cmd process by proc id. I'm working on Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.8. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do - this code seems somewhat misguided. Nonetheless, you may try `public static string RunCommand(Process process)` instead of `public static string RunCommand(int procId)`.

Comment: ```public static string RunCommand(Process process)``` this worked sir, thanks a lot.